# Why is the navigation bar of one of my viewControllers at the very top and the other navigation bar near the top

Tags: ios, objective-c

In an app that I am writing the navigation bars in the two different view controllers have different margins from the top.

This gap is seen in the interface builder and during runtime.
The left screen is at runtime for the MasterViewController.
The right screen is at runtime for the SendYakViewController

[image: RunTime MasterViewController]
[image: RunTime SendYakViewController]

The left screen is the nav bar highlighted in the storyboard for the MasterViewController.
The right screen is the nav bar highlighted in the storyboard for the SendYakViewController.

[image: StoryBoard highlighted MasterViewController]
[image: StoryBoard highlighted SendYakController]

Why is this happening? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this happen only in Interface Builder or also in the app running on the device/simulator?

Comment: Are they both UINavigationBar?

Comment: There is a gap in the Interface Builder and during runtime

Comment: Yes they are both UINavigationBars

Comment: The navigation bars don't have different margins from the top. They are both at the top - as you can see by the fact that they underlap the status bar. It is you who have "drawn" the first one lower than the second one. — However, there is a difference: the navigation bars have different _heights_. But what you see in Interface Builder is not really useful; you should show screen shots of what happens at runtime.

Comment: They are both navigation bars but are they both inside a UINavigationController interface? If not, it is up to you to get the height of the navigation bar the way you want it.

Comment: The navigation bars are the exact same during runtime. I can upload pictures at runtime. Additionally I can't adjust the navigation bar, as mentioned in apple's documentation: "In a navigation interface, a navigation controller owns its UINavigationBar object and is responsible for managing it. It is not permissible to change the navigation bar object or modify its bounds, frame, or alpha values directly."  From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html